# Automator: action/service on right click on an url

Tags: automator

I keep doing the same thing over and over:

1. Copy a url
2. Run a script with the url as a parameter

> php myscript.php --url "URL"

I'm pretty sure Automator can help here, but I'm completely stuck to understand how. My idea was to create a *service*: right click on the url > service > myscript.

How can I do that, or is there another solution out there?

---

Edit:

Here is what I tried, create a service with an URL as input.
[image: worflow creation]
Unfortunately, the service does not even show up when I right click.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Seems like "Service receives selected URLs" only works with Internet actions. Fortunately you can use the "Get Specified URLs" Internet action to relay the service input to your "Run Shell Script" action.

For example, I used the following automator service to open a selected link in a non-default browser. In my case Firefox but you can use Chrome or another browser.

[image: Automator service using URL input]

Remove any address from the "Get Specified URLs" action so that the list is blank as in the screenshot above. Don't forget to "Pass input: as arguments" In the "Run Shell Script" action if you're using the "$@" notation.

Answer (score 0):

An Automator Text Service might be enough. You can change the **Service receives selected** from **text** to selected **URLs**.

The following article walks through the steps involved and options available, [How To Roll Your Own Text Services](http://realmacsoftware.com/blog/how-to-roll-your-own-text-services):

[image: Automator text service]

Comment: This is exactly what I started to do, but no luck making it work. I have created a new Service workflow that receives selected URLs. Input is only URLs. Then I run a shell script `php /path/to/myscript.php --url $1`. And I chose "pass input as arguments". I am not sure I'm doing the right thing, and the service does not show up when I right click on a URL.

Comment: What have you tried? Please can you expand your question to highlight the problematic step. Maybe include a screenshot of your Automator action.

Comment: I added a few screenshots in the question.

Comment: Does your custom service appear in the **Services** section of the **Keyboard Shortcuts** tab of the **Keyboard System Preferences** panel? See http://www.macworld.com/article/1142419/snowleopardservices.html

Comment: Unfortunately, no.

Comment: This then is the problem to solve; try working through the steps in this tutorial before returning to your own service: http://www.macosxautomation.com/services/learn/tut01/index.html