# Can Finder have a service (control click / right click) to add file cut and paste instead of using key shortcuts?

Tags: macos, finder, automation

I want to add cut command to right click menu in finder.
Do not want to use xtrafinder at this time...catalina (sip)

- defaults write com.apple.finder AllowCutForItems 1 =did not work
- Would there exist an option of adding this specific functionality without disabling SIP. **Solution exists, which means this is possible, but so far, these solutions require SIP disabled**.

Comment: I had an answer ready to go on this. In short, macOS doesn't have any Cut facility from Finder, instead it has alternatives to move rather than duplicate  at the Paste stage.

Comment: @Tetsujin Yes. I know of the commands. Hoping to get Applescript that could encapsulate all of that.

Comment: @Tetsujin we have this covered in https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/12391/why-is-it-not-possible-to-use-the-cut-command-to-manipulate-a-file-in-the-find?rq=1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is it not possible to use the "cut" command to manipulate a file in the Finder?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/12391/why-is-it-not-possible-to-use-the-cut-command-to-manipulate-a-file-in-the-find)

Comment: Where did you come up with AllowCutForItems or are you just hoping it exists? If you wanted to edit this to document what solutions work for SIP - it might help us help you. I’ve edited the title so people don’t keep casting close votes and will edit my answer if I can sort out how to make a service for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked out PathFinder, it does not override native Finder file handling.
Only app appears to be XtraFinder(and others) but with SIP disabled unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

You don’t need to cut on macOS since [copy works as cut when you change how you paste](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/19072/5472).

- command + c to copy
- command + option + v to paste with an instantaneous cut

Comment: Great, now have it so I can right click and not hit several different key commands. If I wanted key commands, I would be using Ubuntu, not OSX.

Comment: I haven’t been successful using Automator for that bit it might work for you desires. - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/146776/automator-action-service-on-right-click-on-an-url